# merging two nuxt project into one app and create single mobile app using capacitor js

Tags: android, nuxt.js, capacitor, nuxtjs3, nuxtjs2

i have two project one in nuxt v2 and other in nuxt v3. i want to create mobile app using capacitor js that has the both project. the projects are connected; for example if user log in in app one it should stay logged in in app two. i created android app for project with nuxt 2 and it works correctly as i navigate in app but when i navigate to a route in project with nuxt 3 it opens browser and go to the navigated route. it should stay in app and uses generated static version of other project.
how can i build single project that two project are sync in it?

i had this idea that put statically generated projects in one single nuxt 3 project and put them in 'public' directory and when route changes is use global route middleware and determine which app should be served. but got nowhere.